# DLL Suddenly Not Loading C# UWP

Tags: c#, c++, dll, uwp, marshalling

I put a dll build in native C++ as a Universal DLL in my project directory of C# UWP app and setting content to copy always it was finding it and then the next day suddenly nothing, constantly getting:

> "Unable to load DLL 'AVEngine.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I am calling with:

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern int OpenForProcessing();
```

I ensured the architecture and build config matches, I have also checked SDK versions (min/target versions), I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check dependencies of your `AVEngine.dll`. Probably some of them missing and because of it Dll cannot be loaded.

Better proper approach to expose old functionality to your modern C# UWP application is to wrap `AVEngine.dll` logic using a WinRT component. Then you can reference this component in UWP application. Article ["Use Existing C++ Code in a Universal Windows Platform App"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186162.aspx) could be helpful.

Comment: Hi Nikita, thanks for the suggestion but now even with a C++ WinRT Component I am getting the same FileNotFoundException. Really painful, all dlls I use are in project folder, add into solution, set to content and copy always. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @SeanRyan Run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what files your application tries to load. You should see what dlls prevent your `AVEngine.dll ` from loading.

Comment: thanks I installed and ran however I could not see anything that clearly showed issues, it is hard to read, perhaps I should learn how to use it. Thanks

Comment: @SeanRyan Yes, first time it's not an easy. Filter only your process events and look for `QueryOpen` and `CreateFile` events with `NAME NOT FOUND` result.

Comment: 5 years later these comments helped me understand what was wrong trying to load a DLL and its dependencies in a UWP app. Thanks!